# Can the ''Galois group" for an inseparable irreducible polynomial of degree 4 be $S_{3}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, separable-extension

Here is a homework question of mine: Exercise 24.3.12, from Shahriari, *Algebra in Action*.

> $f\in F[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree 4, and let $E$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $F$. Can Gal$(E/F)\cong S_{3}$?

Note that, the book defines Gal$(E/F)$ as Aut$(E/F)$, the collection of automorphisms of $E$ which fix $F$.

If $f$ is separable, it is easy because the Galois group has to be a transitive subgroup of $S_{4}$, so it cannot be $S_{3}$.

My problem is when $f$ is inseparable, can we get a polynomial with its Galois group $S_{3}$?

Or more generally, what kind of group can be Aut$(E/F)$ for some $f$, when $f$ is inseparable?

Comment: If the polynomial $f$ is inseparable, then $E$ will not be a Galois extension of $F$. Hence we also do not have a group that we call Galois group then. Do you just want to understand $\text{Aut}(E/F)$ instead?

Comment: @TMO As I said in my post, the book defines the Galois group in a different way, and I want to understand Aut$(E/F)$ (which is called the galois group in my textbook).

Comment: No, that is the normal definition. But you only call it Galois group if your extension is Galois. Otherwise it is just the automorphism group of the extension.

Comment: $F$ is an arbitary field ? I ask because if $F$ has characteristic $0$ or is finite, $f$ must be seperable.

Comment: @Peter Yes, F is an arbitrary field. I think the homework question probably made a mistake (since it is too hard), but I do want to know the answer to my question.

Comment: @TMO In this textbook, it defines a Galois group in this way. There are many other books using the same definition, for example, Rotman's Advanced Modern Algebra (a famous book).

Comment: @TMO: Many books call it the “Galois group” in all cases. Hungerford is one of the main books that calls it a Galois group even when the extension is not a Galois extension. And by the same token, many authors denote the automorphism groups, even when they don’t call it “the Galois group” by $G(F/K)$ or $\mathrm{Gal}(F/K)$. I seem to recall Lang does something like that...

Comment: Chiming in with Arturo Magidin. Jacobson uses the same notation for the automorphism group irrespective of whether the extension is Galois or not.

Comment: ...Ian Stewart also uses "Galois group" in all cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is inseparable, then $f'=0$ (since $f$ is irreducible). Hence necessarily $F$ has characteristic $2$ and $f=X^4+aX^2+b$.

If $\alpha,\beta\in F_{alg}$ are roots of $f$, then $\alpha^4-\beta^4+a(\alpha^2-\beta^2)=0= (\alpha-\beta)^2((\alpha-\beta)^2+a)=0$ (because we are incharacteristic $2$). So either $\beta=\alpha$ or $\beta=\alpha+\sqrt{a}$. It follows that the splitting field $E$ of $f$ is generated by a fixed root $\alpha$ , which has degree $4$ over $F$, and $\sqrt{a}$, which has degree $1$ or $2$ over $F$, hence also degree $1$ or $2$ over $F(\alpha)$.

Thus$[E:F]=[F(\alpha)(\sqrt{a}):F(\alpha)][F(\alpha):F]=4$ or $8$. In particular, the degree cannot be $6=\vert S_3\vert$.